# JPQL Multiple Left Joins on Unrelated Classes

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I have three tables with columns (bad fake names):

```
STUDENT (student_id)
STUDENT_UNIQUE_INFO (student_unique_info_id, student_id)
STUDENT_OTHER_INFO (student_other_info_id, student_id)
```

I wish I could change the schema but I can't.
Some students don't have unique_info and/or other_info.

My result set would be like:

```
STUDENT_ID | STUDENT_UNIQUE_INFO_FIELDS... | STUDENT_OTHER_INFO_FIELDS...
```

Where the fields could sometimes be null if the student didn't have any.

Problem is [most examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498949/jpql-multiple-left-join-with-one-class) would have STUDENT containing the IDs of the other tables, I don't have that option.

I tried something like (outputting to a new obj that takes in all 3 of the tables used to join this thing)

```
SELECT NEW path.to.outputObj(S,
       (SELECT SUI
       FROM path.to.SUI SUI
       WHERE S.studentId = SUI.studentId),
       (SELECT SOI
       FROM path.to.SOI SOI
       WHERE S.studentId = SOI.studentId))
       FROM STUDENT S
```

But it blew up because some students have multiple entries in student_other_info.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I'm just a bit lost at how to even go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map those other two tables as lists that could contain 0..n rows for each student.

```
class Student {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student");
   List<StudentUniqueInfo> studentUniqueInfoList;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student");
   List<StudentOtherInfo> studentOtherInfoList;
   ...
}
```

And then **StudentUniqueInfo.java** and **StudentOtherInfo.java** would each have a field

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID")
 private Student student;
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and would be lovely instead of writing some insane JPQL. I'm going to try this out now.

Comment: You answer 100% works. I'm just curious if there is a way to get it to return a list of students, returning a different line item for each different other_info. So if one student had 5 other_info. I would get back 5 rows. I can easy code this out manually, but I figured I'd check. Thanks either way!

Comment: Never done that, but check out this post for some ideas about mapping a class across multiple tables.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668350/how-to-map-one-class-with-multiple-tables-in-hibernate-javax-persistance